# Mail Landing in Gmail Spam folder

Tags: email, gmail, email-spam

After updating DKIM DMARC and SPF email is still landing in Gmail SPAM folder.

In the email header, it is showing DKIM DMARC and SPF Pass and domain and IP address not black listed in https://postmaster.google.com/

Please let us know is there any changes has done in the Google Mail policy.

Is there any other steps we need to follow to receive the emails in Gmail Inbox.

Comment: Any news on the topic? We have setup our email services correctly (10/10 at http://mail-tester.com ), still Gmail categorizes a lot of the emails as spam.